# I can't get Fluidbox (v1.3) working ...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On [this site](http://www.villaesma.es/txp) (Chrome is ok) I'm trying to implement [Fluidbox](http://codepen.io/terrymun/full/JKHwp) ... a beautiful, minimal lightbox (jQuery) with a clever [imageloading](http://goo.gl/s73ge) trick.

CSS:

```
.fluidbox {
    outline: none;
}
#fluidbox-overlay {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-out;
    cursor: -moz-zoom-out;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 500;
}
.fluidbox-wrap {
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 400;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
.fluidbox-opened .fluidbox-wrap {
    z-index: 600;
}
.fluidbox-ghost {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

One way or another it seems that the z-index(es) doesn't put the lightbox (image) on top of everything. It looks as if the enlargement is 'captured' in it's own HTML ... !?

Some help is highly appreciated.

++++

Partly solved ... the CSS of the menu ([ScrollIt.js](http://goo.gl/fNi9OX)) was interferring (z-index) with the CSS of [Fluidbox](http://codepen.io/terrymun/full/JKHwp). Now Fluidbox is working and is on top of every element except the fixed menu. That's a pity ... and I don't know how to solve that. I will ask the devs.

Answer (score 0):

Fluidbox author here.

According to the docs, you can either (1) alter the `stackIndex` setting of Fluidbox so it is greater than that of the fixed navigation menu, or (2) reduce the z-index value of the said fixed navigation menu.

v1.4.1 was released yesterday so it probably contains some crucial bug fixed since the version you're using was released.

Comment: Thanks Terry. I'll have a look. For now: on my iPhone 5 (8.1) in Chrome and Safari the H1 on [terrymun.github.io/Fluidbox](http://terrymun.github.io/Fluidbox) is not nicely centered > [screendump](http://i.glui.me/1GKSKxd)